# I dont see my tests running

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am new to unit testing but something weird is happening with my test in Visual studio. I was able to run all the tests fine in the past but this morning I can not run or Debug the tests. when I run the tests out put window keeps on saying "0 succeeded 0 failed". Test section does not say anything. I am not sure what is happening.

When I try to debug the test, it does not hit the break point. I am not sure why would build engine not pick up the test and show me the test result.

I am suspecting that something might have changed in my visual studio but dont know if there is something specif that I should be looking into?

Comment: There is no information here to go on. Can you provide a screenshot of your test window?

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild the entire solution?

Comment: Yes I did. That does not seem to help.

Comment: Does the test "default processor architecture" match that of your latest build?

Comment: @Vlad: yes it matches and actually my code in different branch is able to run tests all fine. which also means that there is not anything wrong with Visual studio. There must be something on my solution settings which has created this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I dont know how anyone never saw this issue but After a long research I came across this thread and the solution to delete TestResults solved my issue once and for all. The answer was posted on following thread:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770250/running-unit-tests-fails-with-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is not registering any tests, you might not be building the test assembly.  Check this in your Build Configuration:

[image]